# how to model a study_program into Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I'm working a Rails application that enables students to register an absence for an exam.

These are the models

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :absences
  has_many :courses, through: :absences
end

class Absence < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :course
end

class Course < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :absences
  has_many :users, through: :absences
end
```

As you can see, I'm using a join_table Absences that holds a foreign_key to Users and Courses

The registration form looks like this:

```
<%= form_for [current_user, @absence] do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :course_id, "Vak" %>
  <%= f.select :course_id, options_for_courses, label: "Vak" %>
  <%= f.label :date, "Datum" %>
  <%= f.text_field :date %>
  <%= f.submit "Afwezigheid aanvragen" %>
<% end %>
```

Now I should enable students also to enter their study_program into the registration form. But I don't know what's the best way to implement this. Should I add a field ('study_program') to the Absences table, or should I model a study_program into it's own model (class StudyProgram).

Any advice is more then welcome, eventually a student should be able, when registering an absence to select his study_program from a select box in the registration form.

thanks for your help,

Anthony

Answer (score 2):

The general rule here is: Is the study program going to store its own information? Is the list of available study programs ever going to change?

If `study_program` can be modelled as an enum, and very very rarely change, then there is no point having its own table.

If, some day, you might want to add more information about a study program, or have administrators add new study programs, it's better as its own model.

As a side note, I'm not quite clear what a study program is and how it relates to courses - more information here might lead to better answers

---

Edit based on comments:

> don't think a study_program will change much over the years. It's also not going to store other information. The only information that's needed, is the name of the study_program

In that case, assuming that the value can be represented as a symbol, the "recommended" storage solution would be an enum - which would be stored in the database as an integer, with the names defined in the codebase. The downside would be that the database would not know each number means, which can complicate some queries. For example, to search Absences that relate to two study programs, you might have to do

```
Absence.where(study_program: [ 
                               Absence.study_programs[:some_program], 
                               Absence.study_programs[:other_program],
                             ])
```

(this can be made easier with proper use of `scope` and `map` - I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader!)

The upside is, you do get convenience methods - `Absence.some_program` will return you all the Absences that are in `some_program`, and `absence.some_program!` will set the enum and save the record.

If you decide to shy away from enums, and want to store your values in a string database field, you will want to create an array of allowed values, and make sure that there is a validation in place on that field, for example:

```
class Absence < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :course

  STUDY_PROGRAMS = ['Some program', 'Another program']

  validates :study_program, inclusion: { in: STUDY_PROGRAMS }
end
```

Otherwise, students will be able to make up their own study programs by POSTing new strings. It also means you can use `Absence::STUDY_PROGRAMS` from your registration form

You won't get any of the convenience methods, but searching will be made a lot more convenient anyway. Just remember to make sure your field is indexed.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your feedback. I don't think a study_program will change much over the years. It's also not going to store other information. The only information that's needed, is the name of the study_program.